# Global Node modules not installing correctly. Command not found

Tags: node.js, terminal, installation, npm

I am having a problem installing global node modules and everything I find online says the solve is just adding -g. Which is not the problem. I believe it's a linking issue or wrong directory issue.

Here is what I do:

```
$ npm install -g express
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/express
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/express
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/range-parser/0.0.4
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/mkdirp/0.3.3
...downloads correctly

$ express myapp
bash: express: command not found
```

However when I run the direct link location to express it works:

```
   $ /usr/local/share/npm/bin/express myapp

   create : myapp
   create : myapp/package.json
   create : myapp/app.js
... Builds app correctly
```

Where the module is:

```
$ which node
/usr/local/bin/node
$ node -pe process.execPath
/usr/local/Cellar/node/0.8.20/bin/node
$ npm link express
/Users/bentonrr/Development/Personal/node_modules/express -> /usr/local/share/npm/lib/node_modules/express
```

In my .bash_profile I have:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
export NODE_PATH=/usr/local/lib/node_modules:/usr/local/lib/node
```

Do I need to change my Node environment to download to correct folder? Is something not linking correctly? I am lost..

Thanks!

Other Specs:

```
$ node --version
v0.8.20
$ npm --version
1.2.11
$ brew --version
0.9.4
OSX Version 10.8.2
```

Comment: It's because /usr/local/share/npm/bin/ is not in your $PATH of your shell. That's why the shell can't find `express`.

Comment: I added: export PATH=/usr/local/share/npm/bin:$PATH to my .bash_profile and it worked. Thanks! Add an answer so I can accept it and upvote.

Comment: In my case, also having NPM installed via Cellar on OSX, my `bin` path, which I set in .bash_profile, is: `export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/Cellar/node/10.5.0/bin`

Answer (score 103, accepted):

Add `$(npm get prefix)/bin` to your `PATH` (e.g., in `.bashrc`), like so:

`echo "export PATH=$PATH:$(npm get prefix)/bin" >> ~/.bashrc`

For more info, see `npm help npm`:

> global mode:
> npm installs packages into the install prefix at prefix/lib/node_modules and bins are installed in prefix/bin.

You can find the install prefix with `npm get prefix` or `npm config list | grep prefix`.

Comment: what about for non sudo using nvm, shouldn't the path be `$HOME/.npm` to the .bash_profile or .bashrc?  I use nvm, so want to make sure im not cross tying things on this.

Comment: For anyone that has installed Node and npm via Homebrew on OSX, the location of the bin folder that you need to add to the `PATH` will be `/usr/local/Cellar/node/VERSION_NUMBER/bin/`.

Comment: In my case, I extended Tim's answer a bit, so that the actual path is dynamic in the bash profile script:
```echo "export PATH=\$PATH:\$(npm get prefix)/bin" >> ~/.bash_profile```
I used ```.bash_profile``` instead, however you can also use ```.bashrc``` as well, in most cases.

Comment: Additional tip: Use `source ~/.bashrc` to quickly update PATH w/o reboot.

Comment: Even though after I use `export PATH=$PATH:~/.npm-global/bin` my terminal is finding global packages correctly, I have to manually type it with every further terminal creation. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 166):

This may mean your node install prefix isn't what you expect.

You can set it like so:

`npm config set prefix /usr/local`

then try running `npm install -g` again, and it should work out. Worked for me on a mac, and the solution comes from this site:

http://webbb.be/blog/command-not-found-node-npm/

EDIT: Note that I just came across this again on a new Mac I'm setting up, and had to do the process [detailed here on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27475650/26510) as well.

EDIT 2: as mentioned by @MEMOGAMER000 in the comments

> For Windows users, you can run npm config set prefix C:\Users\username\ instead of /usr/local/. –

Comment: I am using `nodenv` and there is most likely a better way to solve this issue for my case. However, your solution worked as a quick and dirty fix! I then switched the prefix back to the `nodenv` prefix and I was able to run the package from the `/usr/local path`. Thanks!

Comment: I have spent months meaning to fix this and this is the only answer I've seen that fixed it for me! Thank you SO so much.

Comment: It still doesn't work for me. What can I do? I want to install globally typescript on win7.

Comment: I tried a lot of solutions but only this one did it for me.
For some reason my prefix was set to `/Users/(username)/.npm-global` even though I did a fresh install of everything. I'm also on a Mac

Comment: This will break you if you have installed Node via Cellar.

Comment: Cheers! Worked like a charm!

Comment: Thanks! `npm config set prefix /usr/local` worked for me on MacOS Ventura.

Comment: For Windows users, you can run npm config set prefix C:\Users\username\ instead of /usr/local/.

Answer (score 17):

My npm couldn't find global packages as well. I did what Brad Parks suggested:

```bash
npm config set prefix /usr/local
```

Then I got an EACCES permissions error (DON'T USE `sudo npm install -g <package>`) and fixed it through the official npm docs: https://docs.npmjs.com/resolving-eacces-permissions-errors-when-installing-packages-globally

1. On the command line, in your home directory, create a directory for global installations:

   ```bash
   mkdir ~/.npm-global
   ```
2. Configure npm to use the new directory path:

   ```bash
   npm config set prefix '~/.npm-global'
   ```
3. In your preferred text editor, open or create a `~/.profile` file and add this line:

   ```bash
   export PATH=~/.npm-global/bin:$PATH
   ```
4. On the command line, update your system variables:

   ```bash
   source ~/.profile
   ```
5. Then install a package globally and test it! For example:

   ```bash
   npm install -g awsmobile-cli
   awsmobile configure
   ```

Instead of steps 3-5, you can use the corresponding ENV variable (e.g. if you don't want to modify `~/.profile`):

```bash
NPM_CONFIG_PREFIX=~/.npm-global
```

Comment: hi everyone, I have question. After step 2, I don't find **bin/** in **~/.npm-global**. So , It don't work, right?

Comment: It should still work. Don't forget that `export PATH=~/.npm-global/bin:$PATH` line is in the **~/.profile** file. You get any error?

Answer (score 11):

In my case, The NODE_PATH environment variable was empty. Check whether it is empty-

```
echo $NODE_PATH
```

if the NODE_PATH is empty. Then change  ~/.bash_profile and add NODE_PATH

```
nano ~/.bash_profile
export NODE_PATH=`npm root -g`
source ~/.bash_profile
```

Now install npm modules again and check whether that is being installed on the path `npm root -g`

Comment: This! is my issue when using NVM and the repl's require to have it look for global packages on linux/fedora

Comment: I've got the same problem with NVM.

Answer (score 9):

For Windows users

**Add this to your path:** "%AppData%\npm"

Comment: I wish this answer was weighted higher.

Answer (score 4):

I do not **ever** install any npm stuff, via sudo!  I have my own reasons, but I just try to keep things simple, and user based, since this is a user development world, and not everyone has root access, and root/sudo installing things like this just seems to clutter up things to begin with.   After all, all developers should be able to follow these instructions, not just privileged sudo users.

This particular system is a RHEL7 accessed via SSH:

Frequently one needs various versions of node, so I use NVM https://github.com/creationix/nvm

So with that said, I can show you a working example for `-g` global installs, using NVM, NPM, and node paths not using root.

set your prefix for `.npm-packages` if it isn't already.  (note, thats a hyphen, not an underscore)

```
nvm config ls
prefix = "/home/<yourusername>/.npm-packages"
```

Then adjust your ~/.bash_profile or .bashrc if you prefer  [readup on why and which here](http://www.joshstaiger.org/archives/2005/07/bash_profile_vs.html), with the following information.

```
#PATH EXPORTS
NODE_MODULES=$HOME/.npm                                          
NPM_PACKAGES=$HOME/.npm-packages/bin                           
export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin:$NODE_MODULES:$NPM_PACKAGES         

#NVM ENABLE                                                 
export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"                                   
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && . "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" # This loads nvm
```

That pretty much covers all paths.  For e.g., if you install gulp  like this `npm install -g gulp` it symlinks in `~/.npm-packages/bin` (note thats a hyphen, not an underscore).   (no need for `gulp-cli`, or `gulp-cl`)

You can pretty much replace/comment-out all other node path exports.  You can put this path info below any other path info you already have, safely, without it overwriting that stuff.

Answer (score 2):

Check your  global Node module's binary folder, and add it to your $PATH.

```
npm list -g | head -1
```

If you use [nodenv](https://github.com/nodenv/nodenv), the path will change whenever you install a new global node version. Adding a node path like this solves my problem.

```
"$HOME/.nodenv/versions/$(nodenv global)/bin"
```

Shortcut for adding the path to zsh

```
$ echo 'export PATH="$HOME/.nodenv/versions/$(nodenv global)/bin"' >> ~/.zshrc
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Add the following line to your `~/.bash_profile`

   ```
   export PATH="$HOME/.npm/bin:$PATH"
   ```
2. Load bash profile

   ```
   bash -l
   ```

Answer (score 0):

The problem I had was **missing the binaries** because the user specific **.npmrc** file in my home directory had **`bin-links`** set to `false`, though the `default is true`.

Just in case this is your problem check that none of your .npmrc files have it set to false.

Then re-installing all modules will create the binaries at the `prefix` so your `PATH` can see them.

Answer (score 0):

It may seem like a hack, but setting up `yarn` when possible saves you a lot of node environment headaches for various unix distros.

Answer (score 0):

```
npm config set prefix /usr/local
sudo chown -R $(whoami) ~/.npm
npm update --force
```

works for me