# Node.js -- Command not found for installed module

Tags: linux, node.js, npm, node-modules, httpserver

I had node, npm, and http-server installed and running. However, when I tried to start up the http-server, I got the following error:

```
error: Cannot find module 'child-process-close
```

I have tried uninstalling and re-installing node. That seemed to work just fine, and it looked like it installed http-server properly when I installed it globally with the following command:

```
npm install -g http-server
```

However, when I tried to run the server on a directory (I even installed http-server locally in that directory), I get the following error:

```
zsh: command not found: http-server
```

When I run this command:

```
npm ls -g
```

I get:

```
/Users/amckemie1/.node/lib
├─┬ http-server@0.7.4
│ ├── colors@1.0.3
│ ├─┬ ecstatic@0.5.8
│ │ ├── he@0.5.0
│ │ ├── mime@1.2.11
│ │ └── minimist@1.1.0
│ ├── opener@1.4.0
│ ├─┬ optimist@0.6.1
│ │ ├── minimist@0.0.10
│ │ └── wordwrap@0.0.2
│ ├─┬ portfinder@0.2.1
│ │ └── mkdirp@0.0.7
│ └─┬ union@0.4.4
│   └── qs@2.3.3
└─┬ npm@2.3.0
```

etc...

I can't figure out why it can't find the http-server module. I'm guessing it has something to do with my PATH or where the module was installed, but I don't know enough about these factors yet to be able to do much more. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer to this question here: [Global Node modules not installing correctly. Command not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15054388/global-node-modules-not-installing-correctly-command-not-found)

Brad Parks answer regarding resetting my node install prefix fixed it!