# Trouble installing ionic framework

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, npm, installation

Been trying to install ionic framework to begin app development and keep getting these warnings that restrict me from actually installing the software

I tried updating node but it didnt help

```
npm WARN deprecated node-uuid@1.4.7: use uuid module instead
npm WARN deprecated minimatch@0.2.14: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2 or higher to avoid a RegExp DoS issue
npm WARN deprecated minimatch@0.3.0: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2 or higher to avoid a RegExp DoS issue
npm WARN deprecated minimatch@2.0.10: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2 or higher to avoid a RegExp DoS issue
npm WARN deprecated node-uuid@1.3.3: use uuid module instead
/Users/tyler/bin/cordova -> /Users/tyler/lib/node_modules/cordova/bin/cordova
/Users/tyler/bin/ionic -> /Users/tyler/lib/node_modules/ionic/bin/ionic
/Users/tyler/lib
├── cordova@6.5.0 
└── ionic@2.2.1 

npm WARN In ionic@2.2.1 replacing bundled version of mime-types with mime-types@2.0.14
npm WARN In ionic@2.2.1 replacing bundled version of cross-spawn with cross-spawn@4.0.2
npm WARN In ionic@2.2.1 replacing bundled version of semver with semver@4.2.0
npm WARN In ionic@2.2.1 replacing bundled version of form-data with form-data@0.2.0
npm WARN In ionic@2.2.1 replacing bundled version of request with request@2.51.0
npm WARN In ionic@2.2.1 replacing bundled version of ionic-app-lib with ionic-app-lib@2.2.0
```

Comment: "keep getting these warnings that restrict me from actually installing the software" From the console output that you posted, ionic is installing fine. If you get an Error instead of a Warning, then the package won't be installed correctly. I'd ignore the warnings you're getting

Comment: After i follow through with this i try using some of the ionic commands and none of them are recognized.

Comment: Please provide what command you're putting in your console to bring more information about your error.

Comment: Also, @TylerGiordani could you post the error you get when running the ionic commands.

Comment: '-bash: ionic: command not found' it is basically saying ionic isnt installed when all i got was warnings meaning it should have installed, same when i try any cordova commands, such as checking version

Comment: @RyanZim i think i found the issue, i was able to navigate through the terminal and find and run ionic and cordova themselves using 'open ionic' once in the corresponding directory. What i was reading but could not find a solution to was that the path in my .bash_profile was not updated because clearly it is there and works i just need to navigate to it. Would you know how to update that

Comment: @TylerGiordani This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15623632/7127751

Comment: @RyanZim Thank you for your responses and help, finally figured it out. had to add 'export PATH=$PATH:/Users/tyler/bin/' (where ionic and cordova were downloaded) to my bash_profile. had the syntax all wrong for a couple of hours haha, finally got it tho! thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have an up-to-date version of `Node.js` installed on your system. If you don't have `Node.js` installed, you can install it.

```
Open your CMD enter
 npm install -g cordova ionic
2: install cordova 
npm install -g cordova ionic
```