# Install npm packages to a custom local directory

Tags: node.js, npm

I have a project, and I am attempting to get all my npm packages installed into a local folder, `www/lib` instead of the default `node_modules`.

I followed the docs, and created a ".npmrc" file, with the following contents:

`prefix=www/lib`

I then run: `npm config list`, and get the following output:

`; project config /Users/user/dev/mobile/.npmrc
prefix = "/Users/user/dev/mobile/www/lib"`

So I assume the local prefix is correct, however when I run `npm install`, it seems to ignore the prefix and simply installs to `node_modules`.

Any ideas?

Comment: [prefix](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/config#prefix) The location to install global items.

Answer (score 0):

To install packages into your desired target, go to your project and type:

```
npm install --prefix="/your/path" .
```

`.npmrc` only affects global packages I think

Comment: Ok, but it's something that I want to happen automatically when I run `npm install` in the project. I have thousands of packages that I use, so, unfortunately, that solution won't work.

Comment: Got an alternative for you. Since `node_modules` is usually gitignored, you can softlink `node_modules` in your project's directory to your target dir (`ln -s /target/dir /priject/dir/node_modules`). After that you would run `npm install` as normal.

Comment: That is an excellent solution, will use that as a last resort - thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick-and-dirty guide for setting up a local directory for global npm package installs.

1. Create a directory where global packages will be installed:

   ```bash
   mkdir ~/.npm-packages
   ```
2. Set the npm prefix to the directory created above:

   ```bash
   vi ~/.npmrc
   # Add the following:
   prefix="${HOME}/.npm-packages"
   ```
3. Update the path and man path:

   ```bash
   vi ~/.bashrc
   # Add the following:
   NPM_PACKAGES="${HOME}/.npm-packages"
   PATH="$NPM_PACKAGES/bin:$PATH"

   unset MANPATH
   export MANPATH="$NPM_PACKAGES/share/man:$(manpath)"
   ```

For a more thorough guide, check out:

> [*Global Node modules not installing correctly. Command not found*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54608206/1762224) *(Stack Overflow)*

Which is based on the following:

> [*Resolving EACCES permissions errors when installing packages globally*](https://docs.npmjs.com/resolving-eacces-permissions-errors-when-installing-packages-globally) *(npm Docs)*