# npm install is successful but not able to run the programs

Tags: javascript, npm

I am trying to install the http-server, bower, grunt in my windows machine. I tried to install using npm install the install is successful but when, i try to run the command it is saying command not found. I tried closing the command prompt and execute again. Same result. The file are available in appdata folders.

```
C:\Users\testuser>npm install http-server
+ http-server@0.11.1
updated 1 package in 5.713s

C:\Users\testuser>http-server
'http-server' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

I tried listing the services and the service is installed

```
C:\Users\testuser>npm list -g --depth=0
C:\Users\testuser\AppData\Roaming\npm
+-- bower@1.8.4
+-- http-server@0.11.1
`-- json-server@0.12.1
```

I tried searching for similar issues, but could not find the same.

Comment: Read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15054388/global-node-modules-not-installing-correctly-command-not-found

Answer (score 0):

```
 npm install http-server -g
```

This will install `http-server` globally so that it may be run from the command line.

Comment: @Harry are the locations of both npm and http-server added in environment variable 'PATH' (Both user variable and System variable)?

Comment: npm, npm bin was added, usually npm install will take care because your npm bin directory is already available in path. I re-installed npm and then npm install http-server, it is working as expected. May be my repository got corrupted.