# How to fix 'command not found' for aws-cdk after running the npm install

Tags: npm, aws-cdk

I am trying to install the aws-cdk and in the terminal and I run the `npm install -g aws-cdk`.  As stated [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/latest/guide/getting_started.html)  After npm runs, I get:

```
/usr/local/Cellar/node/9.8.0/bin/cdk -> /usr/local/Cellar/node/9.8.0/lib/node_modules/aws-cdk/bin/cdk
+ aws-cdk@0.31.0
updated 1 package in 1.636s
```

If I try to run `cdk` I get:

```
zsh: command not found: cdk
```

Comment: Could it be that `/usr/local/Cellar/node/9.8.0/bin` is not in your PATH? Can you try to run `/usr/local/Cellar/node/9.8.0/bin/cdk` directly?

Comment: @EladBen-Israel I have similar issue...[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56743700/enoent-error-installing-aws-cdk-node-module) Can you please comment on this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Make sure `/usr/local/Cellar/node/9.8.0/bin` is in your PATH

Answer (score 17):

Installing as root worked for me:
`sudo npm install -g aws-cdk`

Comment: Rerunning `npm install -g aws-cdk` worked for me, even without `sudo`.

Answer (score 8):

In my case, I added this to the end of my .bash_profile:
`export PATH=$PATH:$(npm get prefix)/bin`.
I did that based on information from a [different thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15054388/global-node-modules-not-installing-correctly-command-not-found/25018453).

Comment: This is the only right answer

Answer (score 4):

If you're using `nvm` to manage your node versions, make sure that the `CDK` package is being installed in the *same* version of node you're currently using or the version you *want* to use.

The OP noted their `CDK` was getting installed in `node/9.8.0`:

1. Check the current node version running: `nvm current`.
2. If you see that the `CDK` installation location is different than the `node` version indicated by `nvm current`, you'll need to switch your `node` version using:
   `nvm use <node-version-where-cdk-is-installed>`

In the OP's case, this would be `nvm use 9.8.0`.

Answer (score 2):

What worked for me in mac was adding to the path the bin directory of globally installed node modules.

1. Install aws-cdk by:
   `npm install -g aws-cdk`
2. Try to run it
   `cdk`
3. no command found error
4. make or edit your .zshrc file in your user directory
5. add line to .zshrc with `export PATH=$PATH:/{your_user_path}/.npm-global/bin`
6. execute it `source .zshrc`
7. now `cdk` should work

Pay attention that it is mac based approach.