# ENOENT error - Installing aws-cdk node module

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, npm, aws-certificate-manager, aws-cdk

After running command:

```
       sudo npm i -g aws-cdk
```

gives error:

```
npm ERR! Linux 4.4.0-151-generic
npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "i" "-g" "aws-cdk"
npm ERR! node v4.2.6
npm ERR! npm  v3.5.2
npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/.staging/semver-096e2ca7
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno -2
npm ERR! syscall rename

npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/.staging/semver-096e2ca7' -> '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/aws-cdk/node_modules/@aws-cdk/cx-api/node_modules/semver'
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/.staging/semver-096e2ca7' -> '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/aws-cdk/node_modules/@aws-cdk/cx-api/node_modules/semver'
npm ERR! enoent This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
npm ERR! enoent and is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent 

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /home/user/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! code 1
```

---

Am installing `aws-cdk` module to create private CA & certificates using AWS ACM service

```
{ npm: '3.5.2',
  ares: '1.10.1-DEV',
  http_parser: '2.5.0',
  icu: '55.1',
  modules: '46',
  node: '4.2.6',
  openssl: '1.0.2g',
  uv: '1.8.0',
  v8: '4.5.103.35',
  zlib: '1.2.8' }
```

---

How to resolve this error? Am able to install other npm modules(like typescript)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had this issue just today. I think it is because the Ubuntu apt install of nodejs wasn't working. I uninstalled it `sudo apt remove nodejs`, then manually installed files from https://nodejs.org/en/download/ which was basically just `sudo cp -r` all the sub directories from the download into /usr/local/. It worked after that.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is with the nodejs that was previously installed. Uninstall and reinstall nodejs before installing the cdk. That should fix the problem