# Terminal (zsh) command not found for global npm installs

Tags: macos, npm, terminal, zsh, oh-my-zsh

This is driving me nuts! I did a lot of googling and tried various things. (I do not consider this to be a superuser topic)

I'm having a lot of troubles with terminal lately. I must have messed up somewhere, because it used to work just fine and now I can't get it to recognize my commands anymore neither `nvm` or `global npm` packages like `expo`. It just gives me errors like this:

```
▶ expo      
zsh: command not found: expo
```

```
▶ nvm ls
zsh: command not found: nvm
```

(BTW: `npm`, `brew` and `j` commands are found )

If I do `echo $PATH` I get:

```
/Users/norfeldt/Library/Android/sdk/tools/bin:/Users/norfeldt/Library/Android/sdk/tools:/Users/norfeldt/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools:/Applications/anaconda/bin:~/Library/Python/2.7/bin:~/.npm-global/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
```

(strange behavior is that if I do `echo $PATH` again it returns two times the same output in one line)

A readable version of it (replacing `:` with `:\n`

```
/Users/norfeldt/Library/Android/sdk/tools/bin:
/Users/norfeldt/Library/Android/sdk/tools:
/Users/norfeldt/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools:
/Applications/anaconda/bin:
~/Library/Python/2.7/bin:
~/.npm-global/bin:
/usr/local/bin:
/usr/bin:
/bin:
/usr/sbin:
/sbin
```

My `.zshrc` file looks like this:

```
# Node & NPM
#PATH="/usr/local/bin:$PATH"
PATH="~/.npm-global/bin:$PATH"
#PATH="~/.npm-global/lib/node_modules:$PATH"

# Git
alias master="git checkout master"
alias dev="git checkout develop"
alias hotfix="git flow hotfix"
alias feature="git flow feature"
alias tags="git push --tags"

# Pip - https://gist.github.com/haircut/14705555d58432a5f01f9188006a04ed
PATH="~/Library/Python/2.7/bin:$PATH"

# added by Anaconda2 4.4.0 installer
PATH="/Applications/anaconda/bin:$PATH"

# Android
export ANDROID_HOME=/Users/norfeldt/Library/Android/sdk
PATH="${ANDROID_HOME}/platform-tools:$PATH"
PATH="${ANDROID_HOME}/tools:$PATH"
PATH="${ANDROID_HOME}/tools/bin:$PATH"

alias emu="pushd ${ANDROID_HOME}/tools;emulator -avd Pixel_2; popd"

# Path to your oh-my-zsh installation.
export ZSH=/Users/norfeldt/.oh-my-zsh

ZSH_THEME="avit"

# Autojump
[[ -s `brew --prefix`/etc/autojump.sh ]] && . `brew --prefix`/etc/autojump.sh

# shell startup.
plugins=(git)

source $ZSH/oh-my-zsh.sh

# Load zsh-autosuggestions.
source /usr/local/share/zsh-autosuggestions/zsh-autosuggestions.zsh

# zsh-syntax-highlighting
source /Users/norfeldt/zsh-syntax-highlighting/zsh-syntax-highlighting.zsh

export PATH
```

ANY help would be HIGHLY appreciated!

## UPDATE

Reading the kind answer from @l'L'l and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55384989/618099) I did the following:

Updated my `.bash_profile` to

```
export NVM_DIR=~/.nvm
source ~/.nvm/nvm.sh
```

(it's the only thing in that file)

created a `.bashrc` by `$touch .bashrc` (Might have deleted the old one.. But this is just an empty file..)

Added the following lines to `.zshrc`

```
PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.npm-global/bin/"             # Changed ~ to $HOME
PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.npm-global/lib/node_modules" # Changed ~ to $HOME
...
# Bash stuff
source ~/.bashrc
source ~/.bash_profile
```

Did a `source ~/.zshrc` and restarted my terminal.

***NOW*** the `nvm` AND `expo` works! **THANKS**

Comment: And what, exactly, is your problem? What errors do you get, when you invoke `zsh`?

Comment: @user1934428 I have updated my question (I get errors like `zsh: command not found: expo`)

Comment: Are you sure, that the commands `expo` and `nvm` are in your PATH? What happens with programs in `/sbin`, which is the last element in your path? If you invoke a program from that directory, will it be found?

Comment: I agree with others that your executables are probably not in your path.  For `npm` specifically, you can try running `npm config get prefix` and adding the `bin` subdirectory to your path.  For instance, when I run the command I get `/usr/local` back, and `which expo` prints out `/usr/local/bin/expo` for me.  For you, your prefix could be in a place your `$PATH` doesn't check.

Comment: if I run `npm config get prefix` I get `/Users/norfeldt/.npm-global`

Comment: @mrfred and if I type `which npm` I get `/usr/local/bin/npm` (`npm` is a working command BTW)

Comment: Please add the output of `alias` to your question as well?

Comment: @TarunLalwani what exactly are we looking for in the `alias`?

Comment: Any anomaly that may be causing this :-)

Comment: @TarunLalwani There is a lot of git commands..

Comment: If PATH is getting repeated then probably one of the auto completion script has been messed up and causing this. Because that is the thing that can get called when running a command

Comment: @TarunLalwani there is no alias that starts with `p`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are a few things you might try, the first would be to source `~/.bash_profile` from your `.zshrc` file. It's possible the `nvm` command was setup there and your `zsh` shell simply doesn't know it exists.

> <sub>**Note**: On OS X, **if you get nvm: command not found** after running the
>   install script, one of the following might be the reason:-</sub>
>
> <sub>your system may not have a `.bash_profile` file where the command is
>   set up. Simply create one with `touch ~/.bash_profile` and run the
>   install script again you might need to restart your terminal instance.
>   Try opening a new tab/window in your terminal and retry. If the above
>   doesn't fix the problem, open your `.bash_profile` and add
>
>   the following line of code:</sub>
>
> <sub>`source ~/.bashrc`</sub>
>
> <sub>For more information about this issue and possible workarounds, please
>   refer [**here**](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm/issues/576)</sub>

↑ Since you are using `zsh` instead at `source ~/.bash_profile` & `~/.bashrc` in `.zshrc`.

---

If you used `homebrew` to install, then you might want to add the following into `.zshrc`:

export/source `nvm` installed with `homebrew`:

```
# source nvm
export NVM_DIR=~/.nvm

if hash brew 2>/dev/null; then
    source $(brew --prefix nvm)/nvm.sh
    source `brew --prefix`/etc/profile.d/z.sh
fi
```

`npm` not installed via `homebrew`:

```
export NVM_DIR="~/.nvm"
source ~/.nvm/nvm.sh
[[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ]] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" # load nvm               
[[ -s "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion" ]] && \. "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion" # load nvm bash_completion
```

↳ https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time to try and help me out!  Your answer pointed me in the direction I needed to find the solution. I have updated my question to show my final solution.

Answer (score 0):

I have no OSX to try... but the paths for `zsh` might belong into there:

`/etc/paths`, `/private/etc/paths` or into `/private/etc/paths.d`

Beside that, there's an [auto-complete plugin](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/wiki/Plugins#npm) for `npm`.

Comment: I did add it to `private/etc/paths` but nothing changed - is a reboot or `source` needed?