# Why is 'vue' not recognized as an internal or external command after success with "npm i -g @vue/cli", project creation?

Tags: vue.js

I'm following the tutuorial for Vue Mastery - beginner path, Real World Vue.js. Everything worked until minutes into video 2. I have node installed, npm installed, @vue/cli installed, I can create a project with "vue create proj-name", and "npm run serve" works, but when I try the command "vue ui" I get the error:
'vue' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling @vue/cli and node, restarting my computer, and updating all of my software. My co-worker has the same computer as I do, did everything exactly the same as I did and hasn't had this problem.

Comment: what is your operating system? nodejs version? and the exact version of vue cli?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Global Node modules not installing correctly. Command not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15054388/global-node-modules-not-installing-correctly-command-not-found)

Comment: @KamalAlhomsi  My operating system is Windows 10. I have node version v14.2.0, vue/cli version 4.5.4, and npm version 6.14.8