# My Angular isn't working and I have downloaded the right things for it

Tags: javascript, angular

deji150@Dejis-MBP ~ % npm install -g @angular/cli@9
npm WARN deprecated debug@4.1.1: Debug versions >=3.2.0 <3.2.7 || >=4 <4.3.1 have a low-severity ReDos regression when used in a Node.js environment. It is recommended you upgrade to 3.2.7 or 4.3.1. (https://github.com/visionmedia/debug/issues/797)
^[[B⸨░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░⸩ ⠏ fetchMetadata: WARN deprecated debug@4.1.1: Debug ver^[[B⸨░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░⸩ ⠸ fetchMetadata: sill resolveWithNewModule @schematics/^[[B⸨░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░⸩ ⠸ fetchMetadata: sill resolveWithNewModule @schematics/^[[B⸨░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░⸩ ⠸ fetchMetadata: sill resolveWithNewModule @schematics/npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
npm WARN deprecated har-validator@5.1.5: this library is no longer supported
/Users/deji150/.npm-global/bin/ng -> /Users/deji150/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng

> @angular/cli@9.1.15 postinstall /Users/deji150/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli
> node ./bin/postinstall/script.js

- @angular/cli@9.1.15
  added 104 packages from 67 contributors, removed 150 packages and updated 33 packages in 47.785s
  deji150@Dejis-MBP ~ % ng --version
  zsh: command not found: ng
  deji150@Dejis-MBP ~ %

Comment: The command is `ng version`, not `ng --version`

Comment: Still getting command not found

Answer (score 0):

Does `npx ng version` work?

Its most likely that the path to your global node/bin path is not added to your systems path variable.
Then follow this and it should do the trick
https://stackoverflow.com/a/15623632/2046263