# I can't install my npm package from the registry even though it installs locally

Tags: node.js, typescript, npm, npm-publish

I just published my Node.js/typescript package to the npm registry but I cannot install it from it, even though installing it locally works.

Output from local installation:

```
$ npm i -g .

added 1 package in 9s
```

Output when I try from the registry:

```
$ npm i iffinity -g
npm ERR! code 2
npm ERR! path /home/sotiris/.nvm/versions/node/v18.18.0/lib/node_modules/iffinity/node_modules/iffinity
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command sh -c npm run bundle
npm ERR! > iffinity@0.1.0 bundle
npm ERR! > tsc && webpack --config webpack.config.js
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! src/cli.ts(3,30): error TS7016: Could not find a declaration file for module 'yargs'. '/home/sotiris/.nvm/versions/node/v18.18.0/lib/node_modules/iffinity/node_modules/yargs/index.cjs' implicitly has an 'any' type.
npm ERR!   Try `npm i --save-dev @types/yargs` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module 'yargs';`
npm ERR! src/cli.ts(29,10): error TS7006: Parameter 'yargs' implicitly has an 'any' type.
npm ERR! src/cli.ts(55,16): error TS7006: Parameter '_' implicitly has an 'any' type.
npm ERR! src/cli.ts(60,10): error TS7006: Parameter 'yargs' implicitly has an 'any' type.
npm ERR! src/cli.ts(144,25): error TS7006: Parameter 'argv' implicitly has an 'any' type.
npm ERR! src/cli.ts(171,10): error TS7006: Parameter 'yargs' implicitly has an 'any' type.
npm ERR! src/cli.ts(199,25): error TS7006: Parameter 'argv' implicitly has an 'any' type.
npm ERR! src/cli.ts(207,16): error TS7006: Parameter 'argv' implicitly has an 'any' type.
npm ERR! src/core/models/Story.ts(1,17): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'ejs' or its corresponding type declarations.
npm ERR! src/core/models/Story.ts(5,24): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'html-entities' or its corresponding type declarations.
npm ERR! src/utils/checks.ts(116,19): error TS2503: Cannot find namespace 'cheerio'.
npm ERR! src/utils/checks.ts(151,50): error TS7006: Parameter '_' implicitly has an 'any' type.
npm ERR! src/utils/checks.ts(151,53): error TS7006: Parameter 'snippet' implicitly has an 'any' type.
npm ERR! src/utils/compiler.ts(9,19): error TS7016: Could not find a declaration file for module 'yargs'. '/home/sotiris/.nvm/versions/node/v18.18.0/lib/node_modules/iffinity/node_modules/yargs/index.cjs' implicitly has an 'any' type.
npm ERR!   Try `npm i --save-dev @types/yargs` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module 'yargs';`
npm ERR! src/utils/compiler.ts(89,47): error TS2532: Object is possibly 'undefined'.
npm ERR! src/utils/config.ts(4,19): error TS7016: Could not find a declaration file for module 'yargs'. '/home/sotiris/.nvm/versions/node/v18.18.0/lib/node_modules/iffinity/node_modules/yargs/index.cjs' implicitly has an 'any' type.
npm ERR!   Try `npm i --save-dev @types/yargs` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module 'yargs';`
npm ERR! src/utils/snippets.ts(5,22): error TS2503: Cannot find namespace 'cheerio'.
npm ERR! src/utils/tags.ts(7,22): error TS2503: Cannot find namespace 'cheerio'.
npm ERR! src/utils/tags.ts(40,22): error TS2503: Cannot find namespace 'cheerio'.
npm ERR! src/utils/viewer.ts(1,19): error TS7016: Could not find a declaration file for module 'yargs'. '/home/sotiris/.nvm/versions/node/v18.18.0/lib/node_modules/iffinity/node_modules/yargs/index.cjs' implicitly has an 'any' type.
npm ERR!   Try `npm i --save-dev @types/yargs` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module 'yargs';`

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: /home/sotiris/.npm/_logs/2023-10-15T18_00_56_044Z-debug-0.log
```

I have all of the types it mentions installed as dev dependencies. This is my `package.json` file:

```
{
    "name": "iffinity",
    "repository": {
        "type": "git",
        "url": "https://github.com/zehanort/iffinity.git"
    },
    "version": "0.1.0-pre4",
    "description": "A minimal IF engine with iffinite capabilities",
    "main": "./dist/cli.js",
    "engines": {
        "node": ">=10"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "install": "npm run bundle",
        "build": "npm run bundle",
        "start": "node dist/cli.js",
        "bundle": "tsc && webpack --config webpack.config.js"
    },
    "bin": {
        "ifc": "./dist/cli.js"
    },
    "keywords": [],
    "author": "Sotiris Niarchos",
    "license": "MIT",
    "devDependencies": {
        "@types/cheerio": "^0.22.32",
        "@types/ejs": "^3.1.3",
        "@types/jquery": "^3.5.20",
        "@types/node": "^20.8.2",
        "@types/yargs": "^17.0.26",
        "ejs": "^3.1.9",
        "expose-loader": "^4.1.0",
        "html-entities": "^2.4.0",
        "jquery": "^3.7.1",
        "terser-webpack-plugin": "^5.3.9",
        "typescript": "^5.2.2",
        "webpack": "^5.88.2",
        "webpack-cli": "^5.1.4"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "ansis": "^1.5.6",
        "cheerio": "^1.0.0-rc.12",
        "flexible-tree-printer": "^1.0.2",
        "iffinity": "^0.1.0",
        "npm": "^10.2.0",
        "puppeteer": "^21.3.8",
        "yargs": "^17.7.2"
    }
}
```

And my `tsconfig.json` file:

```
{
    "include": ["src/**/*.ts"],
    "exclude": ["node_modules", "dist"],
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es2016" /* Set the JavaScript language version for emitted JavaScript and include compatible library declarations. */,
        "lib": [
            "es6",
            "DOM"
        ] /* Specify a set of bundled library declaration files that describe the target runtime environment. */,
        "types": ["node"],
        "typeRoots": ["node_modules/@types"],
        "module": "commonjs" /* Specify what module code is generated. */,
        "moduleResolution": "node" /* Specify how TypeScript looks up a file from a given module specifier. */,
        "rootDir": "src" /* Specify the root folder within your source files. */,
        "resolveJsonModule": true /* Enable importing .json files. */,
        "allowJs": true /* Allow JavaScript files to be a part of your program. Use the 'checkJS' option to get errors from these files. */,
        "checkJs": true /* Enable error reporting in type-checked JavaScript files. */,
        "outDir": "dist" /* Specify an output folder for all emitted files. */,
        "esModuleInterop": true /* Emit additional JavaScript to ease support for importing CommonJS modules. This enables 'allowSyntheticDefaultImports' for type compatibility. */,
        "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true /* Ensure that casing is correct in imports. */,
        "strict": true /* Enable all strict type-checking options. */,
        "declaration": true /* Generate .d.ts files from TypeScript and JavaScript files in your project. */,
        "sourceMap": true /* Create source map files for emitted JavaScript files. */,
        "noImplicitAny": true /* Enable error reporting for expressions and declarations with an implied 'any' type. */,
        "skipLibCheck": true /* Skip type checking all .d.ts files. */
    }
}
```

You can also view my whole repo [here](https://github.com/zehanort/iffinity) if you'd like.

I'm a newbie in TS/Node.js/npm publishing, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why does this package reference itself in `package.json`? I mean this file exactly `"iffinity": "^0.1.0"`

Comment: Also why does it have an install command to build it, rather than building it and publishing _the result_? The message tells you what the problem is - the dev dependencies don't exist when you're trying to rebuild it, at install time, so either they're not really dev dependencies or you're publishing the wrong thing. ([Here's](https://github.com/textbook/build-info) an example of a TS-based library published to npm; note the _built JS_ is what's actually published.)

Comment: As @jonrsharpe said - removing `"install": "npm run bundle",` will probably fix the error

Comment: Indeed, you were right both @Konrad and @jonrsharpe, no errors now. But no command line tool either - installation from the registry succeeds, but `Command 'ifc' not found`...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15054388/global-node-modules-not-installing-correctly-command-not-found

Comment: You need to publish the build result, not just (or in fact not necessarily _at all_) the source code.

Answer (score 2):

You have `"install": "npm run bundle"` script which is run **when you install the package**
So it's run when you are trying to `npm i -g ...` it

Rename this script and it'll work

---

Currently, as you can see on https://www.npmjs.com/package/iffinity?activeTab=code , your package is missing `dist` folder in it, that's the reason it won't run

You should include `./dist/**/*`, `./dist` will include only a `./dist` *file*

Comment: That indeed fixed the errors, but I get no command line tool when I install it... It says `Command ifc not found`. I added

```
    "files": [
        "dist/"
    ]
```

in my `package.json` file, but still won't work.

Comment: @Zehanort it didn't get added

Comment: @Zehanort up...

Comment: This still didn't work. I used [this](https://github.com/textbook/build-info) as an example, and the too use only "dist". But I changed it to "./dist/**/*" and still no files were included, as you can see in the updated npm registry page again.